# Selecting a different tab doesn't update the content | Angular

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I created four tabs using Bootstrap and I put a form tag in each of the corresponding tabs. My problem is, even if I change to the other tab, the form data of the first tag remains. How do I change that?

.HTML component:

```
<ul
  ngbNav
  #nav="ngbNav"
  [(activeId)]="active"
  (navChange)="onNavChange($event)"
  class="nav-tabs"
>
  <li [ngbNavItem]="1">
    <a ngbNavLink>Privacy Policy</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <form>
        <br />
        <label>Heading (Privacy Policy)</label><br />
        <input type="text" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Content</label>
        <angular-editor
          id="editor1"
          formControlName="htmlContent"
          [config]="editorConfig"
        ></angular-editor>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Save Changes</button>
      </form>
    </ng-template>
  </li>
  <li [ngbNavItem]="2">
    <a ngbNavLink>Terms and Conditions</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <form>
        <br />
        <label>Heading (T&C)</label><br />
        <input type="text" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>Content</label>
        <angular-editor
          id="editor2"
          formControlName="htmlContent"
          [config]="editorConfig"
        ></angular-editor>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Save Changes</button>
      </form>
    </ng-template>
  </li>
  <li [ngbNavItem]="3">
    <a ngbNavLink>I can't be selected on click</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <p>
        Sed commodo, leo at suscipit dictum, quam est porttitor sapien, eget
        sodales nibh elit id diam. Nulla facilisi. Donec egestas ligula vitae
        odio interdum aliquet. Duis lectus turpis, luctus eget tincidunt eu,
        congue et odio. Duis pharetra et nisl at faucibus. Quisque luctus
        pulvinar arcu, et molestie lectus ultrices et. Sed diam urna, egestas ut
        ipsum vel, volutpat volutpat neque. Praesent fringilla tortor arcu.
        Vivamus faucibus nisl enim, nec tristique ipsum euismod facilisis. Morbi
        ut bibendum est, eu tincidunt odio. Orci varius natoque penatibus et
        magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris aliquet
        odio ac lorem aliquet ultricies in eget neque. Phasellus nec tortor vel
        tellus pulvinar feugiat.
      </p>
    </ng-template>
  </li>
  <li [ngbNavItem]="4" [disabled]="disabled">
    <a ngbNavLink>I'm disabled</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <p>
        Sed commodo, leo at suscipit dictum, quam est porttitor sapien, eget
        sodales nibh elit id diam. Nulla facilisi. Donec egestas ligula vitae
        odio interdum aliquet. Duis lectus turpis, luctus eget tincidunt eu,
        congue et odio. Duis pharetra et nisl at faucibus. Quisque luctus
        pulvinar arcu, et molestie lectus ultrices et. Sed diam urna, egestas ut
        ipsum vel, volutpat volutpat neque. Praesent fringilla tortor arcu.
        Vivamus faucibus nisl enim, nec tristique ipsum euismod facilisis. Morbi
        ut bibendum est, eu tincidunt odio. Orci varius natoque penatibus et
        magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris aliquet
        odio ac lorem aliquet ultricies in eget neque. Phasellus nec tortor vel
        tellus pulvinar feugiat.
      </p>
    </ng-template>
  </li>
</ul>

<div [ngbNavOutlet]="nav" class="mt-2"></div>

<div class="mb-3">
  <button
    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary"
    [disabled]="active === 2"
    (click)="nav.select(2)"
  >
    Select second tab
  </button>
  <button
    class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary ml-2"
    (click)="toggleDisabled()"
  >
    Toggle last disabled
  </button>
</div>
```

```
Active: {{ active }}
```

.ts component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularEditorConfig } from '@kolkov/angular-editor';
import { NgbNavChangeEvent } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: './tabs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.component.css'],
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {
  editorConfig: AngularEditorConfig = {
    editable: true,
    spellcheck: true,
    height: '500px',
    minHeight: '0',
    maxHeight: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    minWidth: '0',
    translate: 'yes',
    enableToolbar: true,
    showToolbar: true,
    placeholder: 'Enter text here...',
    defaultParagraphSeparator: '',
    defaultFontName: '',
    defaultFontSize: '',
    fonts: [
      { class: 'arial', name: 'Arial' },
      { class: 'times-new-roman', name: 'Times New Roman' },
      { class: 'calibri', name: 'Calibri' },
      { class: 'comic-sans-ms', name: 'Comic Sans MS' },
    ],
    customClasses: [
      {
        name: 'quote',
        class: 'quote',
      },
      {
        name: 'redText',
        class: 'redText',
      },
      {
        name: 'titleText',
        class: 'titleText',
        tag: 'h1',
      },
    ],
    uploadUrl: 'v1/image',
    uploadWithCredentials: false,
    sanitize: true,
    toolbarPosition: 'top',
    toolbarHiddenButtons: [['bold', 'italic'], ['fontSize']],
  };

  active: number;
  disabled = true;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onNavChange(changeEvent: NgbNavChangeEvent) {
    if (changeEvent.nextId === 3) {
      changeEvent.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  toggleDisabled() {
    this.disabled = !this.disabled;
    if (this.disabled) {
      this.active = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

When I change tabs, I can see the `active` variable updated but it wouldn't change the form. Why is this happening? And what can I do to change that?

Edit - I've tried with `ng-container` instead of `ng-template` but all it did is stack-up the forms, leaving me unable to use tabs.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz link of it ? that would be helpful to debug the error

Comment: I did try that first but there was some problem with "NgbModule". Although, I was able to install its package, I couldn't use "ngbNavItem" with it.

Comment: Is the content being replaced, such as the labels? Why do you think the form is not changing?

Comment: @Crafted Pod If you see in the HTML file, in both `ng-template` tags I've written different label for each form tag. First label is "Heading (Privacy Policy) and the Second label is "Heading (T&C)". I see only the first label even if I switch the tabs.

Comment: @ab1004 Does it help if you remove `formControlName` from `<angular-editor>`?

Comment: @CraftedPod It does actually! But I need that in order to track the values of the fields. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was `formControlName` which throws the error `formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive`.

Here's how to use the [`<angular-editor>`](https://github.com/kolkov/angular-editor#usage) directive with both [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and [template driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms).

app.component.html

```
<ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" [(activeId)]="active" class="nav-tabs">
  <li [ngbNavItem]="1">
    <a ngbNavLink>One</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <form [formGroup]="privacyForm">
        <angular-editor
          id="editor1"
          formControlName="text"
          [config]="editorConfig"
        ></angular-editor>
        <br />
      </form>
    </ng-template>
  </li>
  <li [ngbNavItem]="2">
    <a ngbNavLink>Two</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <form>
        <angular-editor
          id="editor2"
          [(ngModel)]="terms"
          name="terms"
          [config]="editorConfig"
        ></angular-editor>
      </form>
    </ng-template>
  </li>
</ul>

<div [ngbNavOutlet]="nav" class="mt-2"></div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularEditorConfig } from '@kolkov/angular-editor';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public active = 1;
  public editorConfig: AngularEditorConfig = ...

  public readonly privacyForm: FormGroup;

  public terms = '';

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.privacyForm = this.fb.group({
      text: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AngularEditorModule } from '@kolkov/angular-editor';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AngularEditorModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

We use the [`FormBuilder`](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#using-the-formbuilder-service-to-generate-controls) to create the form controls.

In tab 1 we attach the `FormGroup` directive to the `<form>` element. The `FormControlName` directive binds to the `text` `FormControl`.

In tab 2 we use the [`ngModel` directive](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) to creates a two-way data binding.